# NULL-terminated array of struct types in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to built a NULL-terminate array of stucts

Here is the code: `lzdata.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nist.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    nist_t *nist; /* NIST data */

    nist=readnist();
}
```

The file `nist.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nist.h"

nist_t *readnist()
{
    nist_t *nist; /* NIST data */
    char line[50];
    int len=50;
    int i=0;

    nist=(nist_t*)malloc(sizeof(nist_t));
    while(fgets(line,len,stdin))
    {
        nist=(nist_t*)realloc(nist,sizeof(nist_t)*(i+1));
        sscanf(line,"%s %s %f %lf",nist[i].config,nist[i].term,&(nist[i].j),&(nist[i].level));
        ++i;
    }
    nist=(nist_t*)realloc(nist,sizeof(nist_t)*(i+1));
    nist[i]=(nist_t)NULL;

    return nist;
}
```

The header file `nist.h`:

```
#ifndef NIST_H
#define NIST_H

typedef struct
{
    char config[3];
    char term[4];
    float j;
    double level;
} nist_t;

nist_t *readnist();


#endif
```

The data file, which will be fed to the application via STDIN:

```
2s  ¹S   0.0    0.000000
2p  ³P°  1.0    142075.333333
2p  ¹P°  0.0    271687.000000
2p  ³P   1.0    367448.333333
2p  ¹D   0.0    405100.000000
2p  ¹S   0.0    499633.000000
3s  ³S   0.0    1532450.000000
3s  ¹S   0.0    1558080.000000
3p  ¹P°  0.0    1593600.000000
3p  ³P°  1.0    1597500.000000
3d  ³D   1.0    1631176.666667
3d  ¹D   0.0    1654580.000000
3s  ³P°  1.0    1711763.333333
3s  ¹P°  0.0    1743040.000000
3p  ³D   1.0    1756970.000000
3p  ³S   0.0    1770380.000000
3p  ³P   0.5    1779340.000000
3p  ¹D   0.0    1795870.000000
3d  ³P°  1.0    1816053.333333
3d  ¹F°  0.0    1834690.000000
3d  ¹P°  0.0    1841560.000000
...
...
```

When I compile:

`$ cc -O2 -o lzdata lzdata.c nist.c
nist.c: In function ‘readnist’:
nist.c:24:2: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested`

I've tried changing the line `nist[i]=(nist_t)NULL;` to `nist[i]=(nist_t*)NULL;` and I got:

`$ cc -O2 -o lzdata lzdata.c nist.c
nist.c: In function ‘readnist’:
nist.c:24:9: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘nist_t’ from type ‘struct nist_t *’`

I've tried changing the line `nist[i]=(nist_t)NULL;` to `nist[i]=NULL;` and I got:

`$ cc -O2 -o lzdata lzdata.c nist.c
nist.c: In function ‘readnist’:
nist.c:24:9: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘nist_t’ from type ‘void *’`

There could be a different number of lines in different data files.  I'm seeking to build a NULL-terminated array of `nist_t` data, so I can process it until I get to the NULL element.  Is this possible?

Comment: `NULL` itself is the integer value 0 (though some implementations define it as the pointer value 0). Since you can't mix integers and structures together, what you're trying to do can't work as is. You'd be much better off returning the length of the array by reference.

Comment: You don't need the initial `nist_t` allocation, before the `fgets` loop. Just make sure `nist` is `NULL`. And don't assign to the same variable you pass into `realloc`, think about what would happen in the reallocation would fail, then you loose the original pointer.

Comment: Your array contains objects, not pointers to objects, so you *can't* set it to null. Use an array of pointers instead (but you'll need to allocate memory for each object too). Or better yet: just have an open array and store the count.

Comment: Also, I hope that your `config` and `term` string wont be more than 2 and 3 characters (respectively), since otherwise you will write out of bounds.

Comment: Unterminated arrays and count variables is how most languages do this, including C++'s vector object (which also stores a second count to keep track of how big it can get before needing to realloc)

Comment: @zneak: It's not important here how `NULL` is defined; it can be `0`, or `((void*)0)`, or any of several other things. What's important is that it expands to a *null pointer constant*, and assigning it to a pointer object makes it a *null pointer*.

Comment: @Dave: What do you mean by "open array"?

Comment: @KeithThompson just an array with no cap (no null terminator)

Comment: use memset() function for put null.

Comment: @VinodPatidar: That makes sense only if a `nist_t` object with an all-bits-zero representation can meaningfully be treated as a "null object". It's entirely possible that such a value (with `config` and `term` both set to `""`, and `j` and `level` both *probably* set to `0.0`) is a meaningful non-null value for the type. As far as the language is concerned, there is no such thing as a "null" value for a structure type. You can define your own sentinel value to mark the end of an array of structures, but the language doesn't define such a value as it does for pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
nist_t *readnist()
{
    nist_t *nist=NULL;  /* NIST data */
    char line[50];      /* A single line of NIST data */
    char config[10];    /* nl quantum numbers */
    char term[10];      /* Rotational term */
    float j;
    double level;       /* energy level */
    int len=50;         /* default length of string */
    int i=0;            /* counter/index variable */
    int n;              /* principal quantum number */
    char l;             /* azimuthal quantum number */
    int en=0;           /* error number */

    while(fgets(line,len,stdin))
    {
        (void)sscanf(line,"%s\t%s\t%f\t%lf",config,term,&j,&level);
        if(NULL==(nist=(nist_t*)realloc(nist,sizeof(nist_t)*(i+1))))
        {
            en=errno;
            fprintf(stderr,"Error %d: memory allocation failure\n",en);
            fprintf(stderr,"File:\t\t%s\n",__FILE__);
            fprintf(stderr,"Function:\t%s\n",__FUNCTION__);
            fprintf(stderr,"Line:\t\t%d\n",__LINE__-6);
            exit(en);
        };
        nist[i].config=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(config)+1));
        nist[i].term=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(term)+1));
        strcpy(nist[i].config,config);
        sscanf(config,"%d%c",&n,&l);
        nist[i].n=n;
        strcpy(nist[i].term,term);
        nist[i].j=j;
        nist[i].level=level;
        ++i;
    }
    nist=(nist_t*)realloc(nist,sizeof(nist_t)*(i+1));
    nist[i].config=NULL;
    nist[i].term=NULL;
    nist[i].j=0.0;
    nist[i].level=0.0;

    return nist;
}
```

And here is a routine I used to test it:

```
nist_t *prtnist(nist_t *nist)
{
    int i=0;

    while((NULL!=nist[i].config) && (NULL!=nist[i].term))
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"%s\t%d\t%s\t%4.1f\t%14.8e\n",nist[i].config,nist[i].n,nist[i].term,nist[i].j,nist[i].level);
        ++i;
    }
    return nist;
}
```

Now I've got to figure a way to get the azimuthal quantum number out of the `config` string.

Answer (score 3):

For your compiler the macro `NULL` seems to be defined as `((void *) 0)`, that is a generic pointer to zero. Since `nist[i]` (for any valid value of `i`) is *not* a pointer you get the errors.

The best way to solve this might be to either pass the pointer from `main` by reference into the function and use that, and return the size. Or by passing an integer by reference, and set it to the size.

There is another solution too, and that is to have an array of pointers. Then you need to allocate each `nist_t` structure separately, and free them all too. Then you can use `NULL` to indicate the end of the array. This is actually how `argv` works, it's terminated by a `NULL` pointer (so `argv[argc]` is always equal to `NULL`).

Comment: `NULL` is defined as an implementation-defined null pointer constant. `0` is one common definition; `((void*)0)` is another.

Comment: There's no evidence that `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)` and not as `0`. But it doesn't matter; all that matters is that `NULL` expands to an (implementation-defined) *null pointer constant* which should only be assigned or compared to pointer objects/values.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's clear from the last error message that `void *` is involved, which leads to the educated guess (notice the phrasing *seem* in my answer) that it's defined `((void *) 0)`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't notice that. Still, it doesn't matter how `NULL` is defined -- except perhaps that it makes it easier to understand why that particular error message was produced.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of structures. `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. There is no null value for a structure type -- unless you define some distinguished value yourself.

For example, you could modify your `nist_t` type so it has a member that indicates whether the entire value is valid or not:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct
{
    bool is_valid;
    char config[3];
    char term[4];
    float j;
    double level;
} nist_t;
```

and then mark the end of the array with a `nist_t` element with `is_valid` set to `false`. Or perhaps you can use some invalid value for one of the other members.

This means you'll need to be careful with any code you write that deals with these structures to ensure that `is_valid` is initialized correctly, and that you don't try to use the other member values with `is_valid` is `false`.

Or you can build an array if `nist_t*` pointers, setting the terminating element to a null pointer type assigning `NULL` to it.

But it might be simpler just to keep track of the number of valid elements in your array of `nist_t` objects.

The particular way that `NULL` is defined is not very important here. All that really matters is that it's a null pointer constant. Assigning `NULL` to a pointer object makes it a null pointer; assigning it to any non-pointer is invalid (though there are cases where the compiler, unfortunately, might let you get away with it).

Comment: I just allocated one addition element for the array, and set `config` and `term` to NULL.  It seems to work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mannix: Huh? `config` and `term` are arrays. You can't set them to `NULL`. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I changed the character arrays to character pointers in the typedef declaration.