# How to iterate through a structs array which has null items?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i have an array of structs of size 10 where only few items are assigned, how do i know if the item i'm iterating over is NULL or not?

```
struct child
{
    char *father;
    char *mother;
};

struct child cont[10];
int i = 0;

memset(cont, 0, sizeof cont);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (cont[i] == NULL) break; // Error
    else //do something....
}
```

The above code throws error: `used struct type value where scalar is required`!

Comment: `cont[i]` is not a pointer and therefore cannot be `NULL`...

Comment: so should i use `&cont[i]` instead?

Comment: A struct array cannot have NULL items. There are no NULL structs.

Comment: so how do i find out if the struct item is set or not?

Comment: You need some other mechanism to say whether the array location is in use.  Like a member called `int in_use;` that you set to 1 when you assign to it and 0 when you are no longer using it.  This question has been asked many times before.. here's one that is similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736057/null-terminated-array-of-struct-types-in-c

Comment: Use `struct child cont[10] = { 0 };` to initialize the pointers to null pointers (memset might not do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing the pointers to `NULL` as mentioned in the comments allows you to test the values as you have attempted. Here is an example utilizing a `while` loop to test for both `father & mother` string values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct child
{
    char *father;
    char *mother;
};

int main () {

    struct child cont[10] = {{0}};
    int i = 0;

    memset(cont, 0, sizeof cont);

    cont[0].father = strdup ("Mark");
    cont[0].mother = strdup ("Lisa");

    cont[1].father = strdup ("Tom");
    cont[1].mother = strdup ("Fran");

    while (cont[i].father && cont[i].mother)
    {
        printf ("cont[%d]\n  father: %s\n  mother: %s\n\n", 
                i, cont[i].father, cont[i].mother);
        i++;
    }

    /* free memory allocated by strdup here */

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/structptr

cont[0]
  father: Mark
  mother: Lisa

cont[1]
  father: Tom
  mother: Fran
```

---

**Array of Pointers to Struct**

Yes, you can create an array of pointers to struct and then allocate memory as needed. This allows you to test `if (cont[i])`. In essence you are doing the same thing, but in the first case, you declare 10 structs. You can never test just `cont[i]` in that case, because it is not a pointer (not to mention it always has an address, whether the strings are filled or not).

In this case you create 10 pointers to structs all set to NULL (by virtue of using `calloc` instead of `malloc` to initialize them). When you actually use one-of-the-10, you allocate memory for the struct giving it an address where before it was NULL. This allows you to iterate over your 10 pointers to find out which are in use. This is a very flexible technique and can be applied to a large number of different data structures. I hope it helps. Here is an example (same output):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 10

struct child
{
    char *father;
    char *mother;
};

int main () {

    /* create MAXS (10) pointers to child set to NULL */
    struct child **cont = calloc (MAXS, sizeof(struct child*));
    int i = 0;

    cont[0] = malloc (sizeof(struct child));  /* allocate as needed */
    cont[0]-> father = strdup ("Mark");
    cont[0]-> mother = strdup ("Lisa");

    cont[1] = malloc (sizeof(struct child));  /* allocate as needed */
    cont[1]-> father = strdup ("Tom");
    cont[1]-> mother = strdup ("Fran");

    while (cont[i])     /* now simply test if pointer is not NULL   */
    {
        /* you can check father/mother individually if desired
           here we simply rely on printf outputting (null) if
           either father or mother does not point to a string */

        printf ("\ncont[%d]\n  father: %s\n  mother: %s\n", 
                i, cont[i]-> father, cont[i]-> mother);
        i++;
    }

    /* free memory allocated to cont & by strdup here */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer, i'm still noob in c but i feel that it's redundant to do it this way. Is there another way where i can use pointers and do something like `if (cont[i] != NULL)` or `if (ptr != NULL)`?

Comment: Sure, look at my second example. **Note:** the use of `calloc` to initialize the pointers to `NULL`.

Comment: one noob question, why is there braces around `cont[i]`, isn't it a pointer to a child struct? can i not just do `cont[i]->father` instead?

Comment: Since it is a pointer, without any dereference, there is really no need. In other situations, you will use the parens `( )` to prevent operator precedence from causing problems. Simply remove them here.

Comment: Glad I could help. Save this trick in your C toolbox. You will end up using it over-and-over again.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `cont` is not a pointer so checking it against `NULL` is not right.
As you might be knowing once you have created an array as done in your code you are already allocating memory for your structure variables even though u might or might not use it.
So your question of asking "how do i know if the item i'm iterating over is NULL or not?" make no sense.
If you want to check whether you have filled the value for your struct members are not then add one more field in your structure which notifies whether struct members are filled are not.

```
struct child
{
    boolean is_valid;
    char *father;
    char *mother;
};
```